# More memory-efficient struct representation in Python?

Tags: python, c, struct, cython, ctypes

I have the equivalent of a classic `Point` struct that I'm trying to create.

```
from collections import namedtuple
Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
```

However, I'll only need limited functionality (access by attribute name) and none of the extra overhead of namedtuples (e.g. length, index access, `__contains__` etc.) Moreover, my use case also has fixed types for `Point.x` and `Point.y` so maybe there's a further hack that relies on the static typing guarantees.

Is there something with even less memory overhead? Perhaps a `ctypes` or `Cython` solution?

Comment: Custom class with `__slots__`? You can see what namedtuple does: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L310.

Comment: @jonrsharpe `namedtuple` instances come with `__slots__` out of the box.

Comment: @EliKorvigo yes, but also a bunch of stuff the OP says they don't want (although it's not much in the way of "overhead" as they don't exist per-instance). I've added a link to show that, anyway.

Comment: @Katie Yes, Cython is an option.

Comment: if you need an array of points, you can use an array, or numpy. And of course you do - because if you had just one point, you wouldn't be concerned about its memory consumption!

Comment: Don't confuse class functionality (e.g. methods etc) with per instance memory use.  That namedtuples overhead doesn't take much memory, and doesn't change as you create more tuples.  And by using `slots` it skips the usual per instance `dict`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, creating a Cython extension will be the easiest way to reduce memory impact. Attributes of Cython extension types are stored directly in the object’s C struct and the set of attributes is fixed at compile time (much like Python's `__slots__`).

```
cdef class Point:

    cdef readonly double x, y  # C-level attributes

    def __init__(self, double x, double y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Point({}, {})'.format(self.x, self.y)
```

Answer (score 0):

**For the cases when Cython is not the option**

There is a way to reduce the memory footprint:

```
>>> from recordclass import dataobject
>>> class Point(dataobject):
...    x:int
...    y:int
>>>
>>> p = Point(1,2)
>>> class Point2(object):
....   __slots__ = ('x', 'y')
....   def __init__(self, x, y):
....      self.x = x
....      self.y = y
>>>
>>> p2 = Point2(1,2)
>>> from sys import getsizeof as sizeof
>>> sizeof(p2) - sizeof(p)
24
```

The difference is equal to the size of extra space used for cyclic garbage collection support.